# c++ calls to fortran and back

Tags: c++, performance, fortran, mpi, interprocess

In my c++ code (my_app) I need to launch external app (app_ext) that dynamically loads my library (dll,so) written in fortran (lib_fort).  From this library (lib_fort) I need to call back to some method from my_app, synchronously.

So its like that:
(my_app) --launches--> (app_ext) --loads--> (lib_fort) --"calls"--> (my_app)

app_ext is not developed by me.

Do you have any suggestions how to do it, and what's most important, do it efficiently??

**Edit:**

Clarification. Launching external app (app_ext) and loading my library from it (lib_fort) will happen only once per whole program execution. So that part doesn't need to be ultra-efficient. Communication between lib_fort and my_app is performance critical. Lib_fort needs to "call" my_app millions of times.

The whole point is about efficient inter-process communication.
My_app role after launching app_ext is to wait and serve "calls" from lib_fort. The tricky part is that solution needs to work both for distributed and shared memory environment, i.e. both my_app and app_ext+lib_fort on single host (1) and my_app and app_ext+lib_fort on different machines (2).

In (1) scenario I was thinking about MPI, but I'm not sure if it is possible to communicate with MPI between two different applications (in contrast to single, multi-process, MPI application).

In (2) scenario probably some kind of inter-process communication using shared memory? (or maybe also MPI?)

Comment: It takes a certain amount of time to launch an app and then for it to load a dll. It will be quicker the second time due to file caching. So do that as few times as possible.

Comment: Thank you. I clarified my question. The part you are mentioning is of less importance - my biggest concern is about inter-process communication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, the real issue is how to communicate between processes. (Forget MPI, that's for a different kind of problem.) You may be talking about COM (Component Object Model) or RPC (Remote Procedure Call) or pipes, but underneath it's going to be using sockets. IME the simplest and most efficient thing is to open the socket connections yourself and converse over those. That will be the rate-limiter and there really isn't anything faster.

Comment: Thanks a lot - it look like I was on wrong path with MPI.  But what about single machine scenario? Would sockets also be a performance win there? Having single implementation for both cases is tempting :)

Comment: @garret: I would try it and see. Then the sockets would be acting like pipes, and OSs are pretty good at waking up processes that are waiting on I/O, so as a means of inter-process communication I would expect it to be about the most efficient, and you're not messing around with unnecessary context-switches. Basically, you should be able to keep the I/O channel almost 100% busy, where stack samples almost all show you in I/O wait. IME, it's amazing how fast you can make those things go.